# Switching focus from Chrome to PhpStorm broken

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, focus, fedora, wayland

Since last week my desktop drives me crazy. While I'm developing webpages, I'm jumping from Google Chrome over developer tools to PhpStorm and vis versa.
In some cases, I cannot reproduce, PhpStorm doesn't get the focus. I have to do many clicks and window movement to bring PhpStorm to input.

Running Fedora 37, Wayland, PhpStorm 2022.3.1, 2022.3.2, 2023.1 EAP

Comment: Sounds like/could be https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-4445/AltTab-doesnt-focus-IDE-window-on-Ubuntu-22.04-in-Wayland-session

Comment: damn - I googled that for hour and thought, this is a new mxsteini-only-problem. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: Just in case: the issue is not on JetBrains IDE side, it's Wayland/mutter/whatever -- check the comments there. If you can identify and fix it, please consider answering your own question(which you can accept later) -- answered question is more visible in the search results and will help others in a similar situation. TA